# About FDQuery with TIdTcpServer

Tags: delphi, indy, firedac

How can i prevent the excessive memory consumn who TFDQuery cause at application running with a TIdTcpServer?

i create the TFDQuery at runtime and after use i destroy it on OnExecute event of TIdTcpServer:

```
Query             := TFDQuery.Create(Cn);
Query.Connection  := Cn; 
Query.SQL.Text    := 'update table set column = 0 where ip = :ip';
Query.Params.ParamByName('ip').Value := ip;
Query.ExecSQL;
FreeAndNil(Query);
```

every new connection perform a select/insert/update at MSSQL, so i always create/destroy the object, but the memory still increasing (i'm testing with an client who create various connections at TcpServer)

i already tested and if i remove the TFDQuery from OnExecute application memory always be fine on tests.

`cn` is the TFDConnection who are always active and are created at application startup and destroyed on application close.

Comment: That would imply that the original code was raising an exception that you were not catching, bypassing the call to `FreeAndNil(Query)`, which was fixed by adding the `try..finally` block

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. If you've found a solution and want to share it, post an answer in the space below that is desigined for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Why do you go through the rigmarole of creating/freeing an FDQuery each time?  Why not simply call `Cn.ExecSql()`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using this method of creation/destroy at runtime:

```
with TFDQuery.Create(nil) do
        begin
          try
            Connection := Cn;
            SQL.Text := 'update table set column = 0 where ip = :ip';
            Params.ParamByName('ip').Value := ip;
            ExecSQL;
          finally
            Free;
          end;
        end;
```